# cron job not running as root user in digital ocean droplet

Tags: bash, cron, digital-ocean

I created this test bash script

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "hello"

mkdir  "/karan/washere"
```

cron job i created, i want to run this cron job to run every min and want the log

```
#testing if cron job workes or not 
1 * * * * /user/local/bin/bash /root/test.sh  &> /root/crontest.log
```

I am signed in the droplet as root user

I also have given the permission for the script, using

```
sudo chmod u+x test.sh
```

I tried to log the syslog using

```
sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

but didn't show there also,

let me know if you need any more info or other context,

Comment: `&>` is a bashism, and I doubt that cron supports it; try `> /root/crontest.log 2>&1` instead. Also, is bash actually in /user/... or /usr/...?

Comment: From the cron tag: Questions about configuring cron for systems or administration are OFF TOPIC.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` uses `sh` to interpret the commands, not `bash`. `sh` has less features and the `&>` is not valid in `sh`.

A better way for your line in the crontab would be:

```
1 * * * * /user/local/bin/bash /root/test.sh  >> /root/crontest.log 2>> /root/crontest.err
```

This will append to the logging instead of overwriting, and it will separate log from errors.

If you want, however, you can force `cron` to use `bash` instead of `sh`. Your crontab should then be:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
#testing if cron job workes or not 
1 * * * * /user/local/bin/bash /root/test.sh  &> /root/crontest.log
```

Comment: I tried it, the dir is not created but script is running

Comment: So, the cron-problem is solved. If you doe the `mkdir` by hand, does that work? does `/karan` exist? do you have write permissions to `/karan`?

Comment: if i do manually mkdir it works, works with script also, but doesn't work with automated(cron) bash script, I have given the permission(chmod u+x)

Comment: If `mkdir` fails, it produces some error message, which should be in the `.err` or the log file. What is the message?